# How to extend SSL certification to another API under same domain?

Tags: caddy

I'm running on node my website in eletron under [www.site.com](http://www.site.com) under the door, this domain have SSL and it's working fine but the another api running in eletron too doesn't have the SSL certification and don't know why. [www.site.com:25000/api/data](http://www.site.com:25000/api/data). I'm using Caddy to get the SSL certification.

Am i losing something here!?